# Better way to extend data members of C++ class / struct

Tags: c++, oop, class, containers

I have this problem again and again... and still have not a satisfactory answer...

Especially when I put the class into a container, later on I need to record more information on every element in the container during a specific processing, but after processing I do not need the extra information anymore....

I often found some libraries try to solve the above situation by defining a void* in their data structure to provide user-defined data structure extension. Just the same described in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749974/whats-void-userdata-exactly).
But it produces memory / resource handling problem... and other problems that I feel this approach is error-prone.

In the modern day of object-oriented programming, I am thinking of
using inheritance & polymorphism. Use base class's pointer in the container, but then I have to add derived class's accessor into the base class.  It is kind of strange...

is there any other better ways to extend a class's property while maintain container comparability in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to store extra data about a object without actually compromising the integrity of the object itself is to store a pair of data in the container instead.

```
struct User { ... };
struct ExtraData { ... };
typedef std::pair<User, ExtraData> UserAndExtraData;
```

Now I can create a container type in C++ which stores both pieces of information together without compromising the independence of either type.

```
std::vector<UserAndExtraData> vector;
```

Comment: Is this still valid when there is no "ExtraData" struct defined? I often found I would define and dynamically add "ExtraData" some else where else in other .cpp / class files.

Comment: @Bossliaw it depends a bit on your usage. My proposal would have you repeat this pattern for every type of data you want to pair with the original object.  If there is no extra data to store then just use `std::vector<User>`

Comment: then the problem rises again... When I have already [std::list<User>] thereby, and I want to add extra data onto the User...

Comment: @Bossliaw in that case you either need to create a new `std::list<>` instance and copy the elements or provide the extra data ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into the [Decorator Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html). You can decorate your objects while processing them then throw the decorated objects away. If there is a lot of shared data you can also look into the [FlyWeight pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html).

Comment: What a gigantic waste of effort for something so simple.

Comment: @DeadMG If your idea of applying a design pattern is to cut and paste code you see online, then yes that is a lot of effort. But in my mind the std::pair<> used in the other Answer is a form of decoration. Being able to apply ideas is a greater asset then being able to copy and paste code.

Comment: I merely took your answer as a suggestion to use code similarly structured as the code in your link- which is a pointless dynamic allocation and inheritance orgasm, compared to the simple `std::pair` of the superior answer. If you don't mean the OP should do something like that, then don't post the link to it in your answer. SO is not a link farm anyway, and your answer doesn't stand without the contents of the links, which is not how it should be.

Comment: Thanks to provide some insight anyway~

Answer (score 1):

"User" could be extended by template parameters. for example,

```
template <typename... Extra>
struct User : Extra...
{
    ...
};

struct ExtraData {...};
struct ExtraExtraData {...};

using ExtraUser = User<ExtraData>;
using MoreExtraUser = User<ExtraData, ExtraExtraData>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objects are in a vector, then a simple approach is to make a parallel vector:

```
void doSomething(const vector<MyObject>& my_objects)
{
  vector<ExtraData> extra_data;
  int n_objects = extra_data.size();
  extra_data.reserve(n_objects);
  for (int i=0; i!=n_objects; ++i) {
    extra_data.push_back(calcExtraData(my_objects[i]));
  }
  // now use my_objects[i] and extra_data[i] together.
  // extra data goes away when the function returns.
}
```

You don't have to modify your original objects, and it is very efficient.

If you have some other container type, you can use a map:

```
void doSomething(const set<MyObject>& my_objects)
{
  map<MyObject*,ExtraData> extra_data;
  set<MyObject>::const_iterator i=my_objects.begin(), end=my_objects.end();
  for (;i!=end;++i) {
    extra_data[&*i] = calcExtraData(*i);
  }
  // now use extra_data[&obj] to access the extra data for obj.
  // extra data goes away when the function returns.
}
```

this isn't as efficient as with vectors, but you still don't have to modify your original classes.

However, it becomes more difficult to maintain the parallel structures if the underlying container can change during the processing.

Comment: When extended data and the base class cross reference, insertion and deletion could be a complex situation.

Comment: @Bossliaw: That's a good point.  I've added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

> In the modern day of object-oriented programming, I am thinking of
>   using inheritance & polymorphism. Use base class's pointer in the
>   container, but then I have to add derived class's accessor into the
>   base class. It is kind of stange...

you don't need to put a pointer to your derived class in your base class when using inheritance. You just need to cast to the derived class. the problem is getting your data into the derived objects when it's stored in the base objects - you can only cast them if they were created as the derived type, even if your collection holds them as the base type. (if they are created as the derived type, then just cast!)

So if you have a collection of BaseC, you can create a new class DerivedC that has a copy constructor that takes a BaseC. You can copy your BaseC object into it, perform your processing on the DerivedC objects and then copy these back into a BaseC object for storage. This uses the Flyweight pattern. Note that if you have a collection of BaseC objects, you cannot just pretend they are DerivedC classes as they will not have the storage to hold all the data members, you need to create new DerivedC objects.

Alternatively, create a new class just for processing that contains a (smart pointer) reference to your base class objects, copy the reference in, perform the processing, delete the processing objects when you're done.

Comment: I have considered adding a "smart pointer to extened data" to the base class / struct, but when using it by parallel container approach...

Answer (score -1):

One simple option is to add a type parameter representing the "extra data"...

```
template<class ExtraDataType>
struct MyExtensibleContainer
{
    ...
    ExtraDataType extra;
};
```

Perhaps if you indicate why this solution isn't sufficient, the true requirements will come through.

Example for int and void*:

```
struct IntOrVoid
{
};

struct IntOrVoid1 : IntOrVoid
{
    int x;
};

struct IntOrVoid2 : IntOrVoid
{
    void* x;
};

typedef shared_ptr<IntOrVoid> PIntOrVoid;

then use MyExtensibleContainer<PIntOrVoid>
```

or altenatively:

```
union IntOrVoid
{
    int x_int;
    void* x_voidp;
};

then use MyExtensibleContainer<IntOrVoid>
```

The problem you are describing has nothing to do with adding an "extra" data type.  The problem you are describing has to do with holding a variant type that can have one of many hetrogeneous types.  There are many ways to do this, it is a much more general problem.

Comment: Still, templated data type is not container compatible because
vector< MyExtensibleContainer<int> > is not the same as
vector< MyExtensibleContainer<void*> >

Comment: Well you need to create a data type that can hold the range of possible values that ExtraDataType can hold, and then assign that type as the type parameter.

Comment: uh.. no, my problem is how to add an "extra" data type on an existing class, where the "extra" data type is the "varient" one. And can be handled properly in a container

Comment: @Bossliaw: Yes, and what I am saying is that that decomposes into two orthogonal problems: (1) Adding extra data to an existing class, and (2) Representing a variant type.

Comment: Just use `boost::variant`, don't use this stuff.

Comment: @DeadMG: As I said there are many ways to do it, unions, inheritence or a variant type like boost::variant, QVariant etc, just to name a few of them.

Comment: @Andrew: A pity that the ones you demonstrate are absolutely terrible.

Comment: @DeadMG: Inheritance and unions are standard and common language features.  By what rationale do you claim they are absolutely terrible?